# What are bifunctors?

Tags: haskell, functor, bifunctor

I'm relatively new to Haskell and having trouble understanding the utility of bifunctors. I think I understand them in theory: say for example if I wanted to map across a type that abstracts multiple concrete types, such as Either or Maybe, I'd need to encapsulate them in a bifunctor. But on the one hand, those examples seems particularly contrived, and on the other it does seem like you could achieve that same functionality simply through composition.

As an example, I came across this code in [*The Essence of the Iterator Pattern*](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) by Jeremy Gibbons and Bruno C. d. S. Oliveira:

```
import Data.Bifunctor

data Fix s a = In {out::s a (Fix s a) }

map' :: Bifunctor s => (a -> b) -> Fix s a -> Fix s b
map' f = In . bimap f (map' f) . out

fold' :: Bifunctor s => (s a b -> b) -> Fix s a -> b
fold' f = f . bimap id (fold' f) . out

unfold' :: Bifunctor s => (b -> s a b) -> b -> Fix s a
unfold' f = In . bimap id (unfold' f) . f
```

I understand the point is to compose mapping and folding functions to create an iterator pattern and this is achieved by defining a data constructor that requires two parameters. But in practice I don't understand how this is any different then using a regular functor and composing the functions with fmap instead of bimap. I think I clearly must be missing something, both with this example and, likely, in general.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it slightly. A bifunctor is just like a two-parameter functor. Gibbons and Oliveira's idea is just one application of bifunctors, just like the standard zoo of recursion schemes is just one application of functors.

```
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d
```

`Bifunctor`s have a kind of `* -> * -> *` and both parameters can be covariantly mapped over. Compare this to regular `Functor`s, which have only one parameter (`f :: * -> *`) which can be covariantly mapped over.

For example, think about `Either`'s usual `Functor` instance. It only allows you to `fmap` over the second type parameter - `Right` values get mapped, `Left` values stay as they are.

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap f (Left x) = Left x
    fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
```

However, its `Bifunctor` instance allows you to map both halves of the sum.

```
instance Bifunctor Either where
    bimap f g (Left x) = Left (f x)
    bimap f g (Right y) = Right (g y)
```

Likewise for tuples: `(,)`'s `Functor` instance allows you to map only the second component, but `Bifunctor` allows you to map both parts.

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
    fmap f (x, y) = (x, f y)

instance Bifunctor (,) where
    bimap f g (x, y) = (f x, g y)
```

Note that `Maybe`, which you mentioned, doesn't fit into the framework of bifunctors because it has only one parameter.

---

On the question of `Fix`, the fixed point of a bifunctor allows you to characterise recursive types which have a functorial type parameter, such as most container-like structures. Let's use lists as an example.

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

data ListF a r = Nil_ | Cons_ a r deriving Functor
type List a = Fix (ListF a)
```

Using the standard functorial `Fix`, as I have above, there's no generic derivation of an instance of `Functor` for `List`, because `Fix` doesn't know anything about `List`'s `a` parameter. That is, I can't write anything like `instance Something f => Functor (Fix f)` because `Fix` has the wrong kind. I have to hand-crank a `map` for lists, perhaps using `cata`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map f = cata phi
    where phi Nil_ = Fix Nil_
          phi Cons_ x r = Fix $ Cons_ (f x) r
```

The bifunctorial version of `Fix` does permit an instance of `Functor`. `Fix` uses one of the bifunctor's parameters to plug in the recursive occurrence of `Fix f a` and the other one to stand in for the resultant datatype's functorial parameter.

```
newtype Fix f a = Fix { unFix :: f a (Fix f a) }

instance Bifunctor f => Functor (Fix f) where
    fmap f = Fix . bimap f (fmap f) . unFix
```

So we can write:

```
deriveBifunctor ''ListF

type List = Fix ListF
```

and get the `Functor` instance for free:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b
map = fmap
```

Of course, if you want to work generically with recursive structures with more than one parameter then you need to generalise to tri-functors, quad-functors, etc... This is clearly not sustainable, and plenty of work (in more advanced programming languages) has been put into designing more flexible systems for characterising types.

Comment: May I ask what sort of work in what sorts of programming languages? Can you point to something accessible? I've been thinking it might be possible to define something like `class Covariant (n :: Nat) p` expressing that `p` is covariant in its `nth` parameter, but I'm not quite sure what that would look like.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I was thinking of bifunctors as superfluous syntactic sugar, but your example of overloading map to take two parameters demonstrates how they're actually much simpler semantically as well. I'm also intrigued by what you were referring to in your comment at the end, though. Doesn't OCaml have polymorphic functors?

Comment: @dfeuer Oh, I was just making reference to the constellation of "universe"-style datatype descriptions that have been developed in DT languages.

Comment: @dfeuer PS, thinking aloud here, but I think a "Covariant-in-parameter-n" class wouldn't be the right way to go. Instead make a more flexible `Functor` which goes between arbitrary categories: `class (Category c1, Category c2) => Functor c1 c2 f | f -> c1, f -> c2 where fmap :: c1 a b -> c2 (f a) (f b)`. Then a bifunctor (after uncurrying) is just a functor from the product category.

Comment: @dfeuer, one example of such work (the only I'm aware of) is [Generic Programming with Indexed Functors](http://dreixel.net/research/pdf/gpif.pdf). If you sacrifice first-orderness they have in the paper, you'll get [something](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Desc/InternalMuSet.agda) quite powerful, but it's not ideal still as you can't e.g. make an index depend on a parameter or define several data types mutually such that they have distinct parameter telescopes.